# Chrome overrides only work when DevTools panel is open

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to remove a particular result from the Google Image Search page. To do that I have the following code:

```
const path = "//h3[contains(text(),'بیاموز')]";
const matchingElementSet = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
const h3 = matchingElementSet.iterateNext();
h3.parentElement.remove();
```

I would like to inject this code into every Google Image Search page, preferably without installing any extensions and 3rd party code.
I tried putting it at the top of the file `m=_b,_tp.js` which is apparently loaded on every Google Image Search result page. It works fine when the result page is already loaded, the DevTools panel is open and I enter a new search term in the search box. But when I close the DevTools panel and do a fresh search the code doesn't run.
Now, I can confirm that Enable Local Overrides is checked. I have also allowed Chrome to write to disk. The overridden file is also in the right folder. But it is ignored until I open the DevTools and enter a new term in the already loaded search result page.